# Using MongoDB Sink Connector to update existing documents by a different primary key

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

I'm attempting to setup a MongoDB Sink Connector via Confluent Cloud which keeps data synced between pgsql and MongoDB.

I'm expecting the config below to update an existing document based on the `id` (int) field (not _id - objectId), however it just creates a new document in MongoDB when consumed. Documents from pg will not contain the _id field, therefore we need the lookup done on our pgsql primary key (id).

Any ideas why this isn't working as I would expect?

```
 {
  "connector.class": "MongoDbAtlasSink",
  "name": "mongodb-sink",
  "kafka.api.key": "mykey",
  "kafka.api.secret": "mysecret",
  "input.data.format": "JSON",
  "topics":"mytopic",
  "connection.host": "myhost",
  "connection.user": "myuser",
  "connection.password": "mypassword",
  "database": "mydatabase",
  "delete.on.null.values": "false",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "document.id.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy",
  "document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.list":"id",
  "document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type":"AllowList",
"writemodel.strategy":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy"
}
```

Comment: Tried adding a unique index to the id column without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`key.projection.type` and `value.projection.type` are apparently unsupported in the cloud version, so it won't work with that config.

[Cloud Connector Limitations](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/limits.html#cc-mongo-db-sink-limits)